# Enforce partition be stored on the specific executor

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd, shuffle

I have 5-partitions-RDD and 5 workers/executors.

*How can I ask Spark to save each RDD's partition on the different worker (IP)?*

*Am I right if I say Spark can save few partitions on one worker, and 0 partitions on other workers?*

Means, I can specify the number of partitions, but Spark still can cache everything on a single node.

Replication is not an option since RDD is huge.

## Workarounds I have found

### getPreferredLocations

RDD's `getPreferredLocations` method does not provide a 100% warranty that partition will be stored on a specified node. Spark will try during `spark.locality.wait`, but afterward, Spark will cache partition on a different node.

[As a workarround](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/getPreferredLocations-td6554.html), you can set very high value to `spark.locality.wait` and override `getPreferredLocations`. The bad news - you can not do that with Java, you need to write Scala code. At least Scala internals wrapped with Java code. I.e:

```
class NodeAffinityRDD[U: ClassTag](prev: RDD[U]) extends RDD[U](prev) {
  
  val nodeIPs = Array("192.168.2.140","192.168.2.157","192.168.2.77")

  override def getPreferredLocations(split: Partition): Seq[String] =
    Seq(nodeIPs(split.index % nodeIPs.length))
}
```

### SparkContext's makeRDD

[SparkContext has makeRDD method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#makeRDD(scala.collection.Seq,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)). This method lack documentation. As I understand, I can specify preferred locations, and then set a high value to `spark.locality.wait`. The bad news - preferred location [will be discarded on the first shuffle/join/cogroup operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250360/in-apache-spark-is-it-possible-to-specify-partitions-preferred-location-for-a).

---

Both approaches have the drawback of too high `spark.locality.wait` can cause your cluster to starve if some of the nodes will be unavailable.

## P.S. More context

I have up to 10,000 of `sales-XXX.parquet` files, each represents sales of different goods in the different regions. Each `sales-XXX.parquet` could vary from a few KBs to a few GBs. All `sales-XXX.parquet`s together could take up to tens or hundreds of GBs at HDFS.
I need a full-text search through all sales. I have to index each `sales-XXX.parquet` one-by-one with Lucene. And now I have two options:

1. Keep Lucene indexes in Spark. There is already [solution for this](https://github.com/zouzias/spark-lucenerdd), but it looks pretty suspicious. ***Is there any better solutions?***
2. Keep Lucene indexes at the local file system. Then I can map-reduce on the results of each worker's index lookup. But this approach requires each worker node keeps an equal amount of data. ***How could I ensure Spark will keep equal amount of data on each worker node?***

Comment: I hope you know that random `@` have no use at all :)  It doesn't notify anyone who isn't already active in a given thread. `spark.deploy.spreadOut` typically worked for me, but as far as I know it is not portable and doesn't provide any guarantees. What is the end goal here? You cache the data, assume no worker faults, but what comes next?

Comment: Have you actually observed spark putting all your data on a single node, or is this just theoretical?

Comment: @zero323 sorry for that. But that `@` wasn't so random, I just choose top 5 Spark users on stack overflow :)  Please look at my P.S. section of the question. Do I really need `spark.deploy.spreadOut`?

Comment: @puhlen That's just theoretical, and I haven't done any tests of this kind. Should I worry about this at all? Please look at `P.S. More Context` section of my question

Comment: Don't worry :) My only point is that @ doesn't work. Reading "more context" - at this scale I wouldn't worry much about skews and not even try micromanaging. What troubles me more is 10,000 RDDs  (I haven't tried so it just a hunch but it may drive some components, including LRU tracking, crazy) and full text search At the first glance I would rather look at some in-memory data grid, and maybe Succinct.